# AJAX Request with Password

Tags: ajax, ssl, curl, passwords, axios

I have the following PHP/CURL. I need to send it via JS/AJAX (Axios)

How to adapt to JS?

```
$username = 'test';
$password = 'test';

$curl_handle = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://example.com/pc_api/index.php/token');
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ':' . $password);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
```

Comment: I think this solves your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5507234/how-to-use-basic-auth-with-jquery-and-ajax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use with [axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios), Use `auth` for basic authentication :

```
axios({
    method: 'get',
    url: 'https://example.com/pc_api/index.php/token',
    responseType: 'json', // default is json
    auth: {
        username: 'test',
        password: 'test'
    }
}).then(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Check [request config params](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios#request-config)